# org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateQueryException: Video is not mapped [from Video]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc

I was trying to work with hibernate to get result from mysql database.

This is Dao object, When I use query.createQuery it gives "table is not mapped" exception.  I've learned the the name in HQL must be the entity name instead of database table name, which is what I didn't go wrong. but when I use query.createSQLQuery it works fine:

```
package com.mondo.mondo_service.dao;

import com.mondo.mondo_service.rest.model.Video;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;


@Repository
public class VideoDao extends BaseDao<Video> {

    public List<Video> findAll() {
        Session database = sessionFactory.openSession();

        // here use createSQLQuery works
        //Query taskQuery = database.createSQLQuery("select * from md_video");

        //here it goes wrong
        Query taskQuery = database.createQuery("from Video");

        List<Video> videos = taskQuery.list();
        database.close();
        return videos;
    }

}
```

Exception info:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateQueryException: Video is not mapped [from Video]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Video is not mapped [from Video]
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateQueryException: Video is not mapped [from Video]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Video is not mapped [from Video]
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:253)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:68)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:49)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    com.mondo.mondo_service.dao.VideoDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$453e97b8.findAll(<generated>)
    com.mondo.mondo_service.service.ReadVideoService.getAllVideos(ReadVideoService.java:23)
    com.mondo.mondo_service.rest.resources.MainResource.getVideo(MainResource.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

This is model object:

```
package com.mondo.mondo_service.rest.model;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity
@Table(name = "md_video")
public class Video implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private int duration;
    private String img;
    private String source;
}
```

I use Configuration.java instead of xml configuration:

```
package com.mondo.mondo_service.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfiguration {


    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DB_DRIVER;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String DB_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String DB_URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String DB_USERNAME;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
    private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager =
                new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

} // class DatabaseConfig
```

Comment: Where is your Video.hbm.xml mapping done? That isn't available in your configuration via the annotations!

Comment: Hi, Can you explain more to me? I think @Table(name = "md_video") is doing the job?

Comment: No @frank, it does not convey the message completely. Please check my answer, if it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've completely gone through the code that you've provided on the question. I feel that there is something missing here in this code.

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

    //Missing-line here, explanation below

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

What was missing is the mapping to look for the Annotated class (Video.class that is mapped to the Database table).

The missing line to add in your code is, as follows:

```
sessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Video.class);
```

You can follow the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html), just in case you need to cross-check the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Happy to help, @frank

Comment: by the time being, the link given is pointing to a 404. Can you maybe update it? Thank you.